# Button Logout for android facebook connect

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Need Help -  I have some code for Logout like this

```
public void logoutFromFacebook() {
    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {

        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Login button visible
                    btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // making all remaining buttons invisible
                    btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnFbLogout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But that code didnt work , when I click logout , and click login again , Im not input username and password again , I want if i click logout and when i click login again , i can input username and password again , Pleasee need solution , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this way when user press logout button you have to execute this code

```
  public void runTestLogout() {
    if (testLogout()) {
        logoutText.setText("Logout Tests Passed");
    } else {
        logoutText.setText("Logout Tests Failed");
    }
}



 public boolean testLogout() {
    try {
        Log.d("Tests", "Testing logout");
        String response = authenticatedFacebook.logout(this);
        Log.d("Tests", "Got logout response: *" + response + "*");
        if (!response.equals("true")) {
            return false;
        }

        Log.d("Tests", "Testing logout on logged out facebook session");
        try {
            Util.parseJson(authenticatedFacebook.logout(this));
            return false;
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            if (e.getErrorCode() != 101 || 
                    !e.getMessage().equals("Invalid API key") ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        Log.d("Tests", "Testing logout on unauthenticated object");
        try {
            Util.parseJson(new Facebook(APP_ID).logout(this));
            return false;
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            if (e.getErrorCode() != 101 || 
                    !e.getMessage().equals("Invalid API key") ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        Log.d("Tests", "All Logout Tests Passed");
        return true;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The main thing is

```
  String response = authenticatedFacebook.logout(this);
```

by running this code you will be logout now you can again log in and you will get empty username and password button

Comment: can u tell me what authenticatedFacebook ??

Comment: ya... its your FACEBOOK OBJECT                                  Facebook authenticatedFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

Comment: Facebook authenticatedFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

Comment: ya , i was change , but still cant logout :(

Comment: I think it's because your built in facebook app is already logged in first logout from that also

Comment: Use your facebook object as a logout also mean from which facebook object you login you must use that object for logout also i think you are creating also new object for logout and login for facebook]

Comment: sorry , i didt understand what u say , can u explain with show some code?? thanks

Comment: use this for LOGIN FOR FACEBOOK AND ALSO LOGOUT FOR FACEBOOK                                               Facebook authenticatedFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);                        use same object for login and logout